# IBOutlets nil and view not loading after presentModalViewController:animated:

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiviewcontroller, nib

On the iPad, I am displaying a viewController using `-presentModalViewController:animated:` and then that viewController displays a second modal viewController by also calling `-presentModalViewController:animated:`.

The problem is that the second viewController does not appear to load its NIB. Looking in the debugger, all of the UIView elements are set to nil, and `-viewDidLoad` doesn't get called.

However, if I go directly to the second dialog from the first UIViewController, the NIB loads correctly. According to the Apple documentation, pushing multiple UIViewControllers loaded should be possible (see discussion for `-dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` for multiple modal UIViewControllers loaded in succession).

Below is my code for calling the second modal UIViewController (the first is called using essentially the same code).  The `dialog.delegate` is based on the same code that Apple uses for the Utility flipSideController sample code, and is only used to notify the parent that the dialog is ready to close.

```
- (void) displayNewGameDialog {
    NewGameDialog * dialog;

    if (iPadDevice) {
        dialog = [[NewGameDialog alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewGameDialog-iPad" 
                                                 bundle:nil];
        dialog.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    } else {
        dialog = [[NewGameDialog alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewGameDialog" 
                                                 bundle:nil];
    }

    dialog.delegate                 = self;
    dialog.modalTransitionStyle     = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    dialog.player                   = self.player;

    [self presentModalViewController:dialog animated:YES];
    [dialog autorelease];
}
```

Comment: How do you declare iPadDevice? Is it an instance variable?

Comment: I cashed the result as an instance variable using this function:

Comment: - (BOOL) iPadDevice {
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(userInterfaceIdiom)]) {
        return ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
    }
    return NO;
}

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was...

The first viewController is displaying a document type window and in its `-viewDidLoad` method I was telling the second dialog box to appear. Because they both were using animation effects they were stepping on each others toes and the second viewController never loaded properly.

The answer was to delay by one second using `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` before the dialog box was initialized.